# Why is animation with TexturePacker drawing a black square?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to use TexturePacker with LibGDX to animate a strip with player animation. However, it's drawing a black box instead of the actual sprites. Is there something wrong with my code?

This is my current atlas file:

```
size: 320, 32
format: RGBA8888
filter: Linear,Linear
repeat: none
idle
  rotate: false
  xy: 0, 0
  size: 32, 32
  orig: 32, 32
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 1
idle
  rotate: false
  xy: 32, 0
  size: 32, 32
  orig: 32, 32
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 2
jump
  rotate: false
  xy: 64, 0
  size: 32, 32
  orig: 32, 32
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 1
jump
  rotate: false
  xy: 96, 0
  size: 32, 32
  orig: 32, 32
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 2
run
  rotate: false
  xy: 128, 0
  size: 32, 32
  orig: 32, 32
  offset: 0, 0
  index: 1
```

Here is the Animation Controller where something is wrong:

```
public class Animator {

    TextureAtlas atlas;
    private Animation<TextureRegion> idleAnimation;
    private Animation<TextureRegion> runningAnimation;
    private Animation<TextureRegion> jumpingAnimation;

    private TextureRegion currentFrame;

    // Variable for tracking elapsed time for animation
    private float elapsedTime;

    public Animator(){

        atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("ninja.atlas"));
        TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion idle = atlas.findRegion("idle");
        TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion running = atlas.findRegion("run");
        TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion jumping = atlas.findRegion("jump");
        atlas.dispose();

        idleAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(1/6f, idle);
        runningAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(1/12f, running);
        jumpingAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(1/12f, jumping);

        elapsedTime = 0f;
    }

    public void render(SpriteBatch batch){
        elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); // Accumulate elapsed animation time

        System.out.println(currentFrame);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(idleAnimation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true), 100, 50); // draw current frame at (50, 50)
        batch.end();
    }

}
```

I'm not getting any error messages, the black box is just drawn instead of the sprites.

Comment: the Frames in the atlas file should be named: idle_0, idle_1, run_0, run_1, jump_0 so Animation can find the Region in your atlas. Here is the wiki to the Animation class where is written that you must name your frames with _0 _1 etc.: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation

Comment: Like Morchul said, the first frame starts with index 0, not 1 as you have in your atlas.

Answer (score 0):

The Frames in your atlas should be named like this:

- idle_0
- idle_1
- run_0
- run_1
- jump_0

The Animation can only find the TextureRegions of your Animation in your Atlas if you name the Regions with an underscore and then the Frame number.

You can find the description in the LibGdx wiki: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation

> TexturePacker and TextureAtlas provide a convenient way to generate animations. All the source images of an animation should be named with an underscore and frame number at the end, such as running_0.png, running_1.png, running_2.png, etc. TexturePacker will automatically use these numbers as frame numbers (so long as the packing parameter useIndexes is left true).

---

Additional you should set the PlayMode of your Animation to `LOOP` if you want that your animation runs more than once. The Default PlayMode is `NORMAL` so after all frames are done you always will see the last Frame rendered instead of beginning by the first frame.

You can set PlayMode in Constructor:

```
idleAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(1/6f, idle, Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
```

or with `setPlayMode` method:

```
idleAnimation.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Many Android devices do not support non-power-of-two texture dimensions, and when you try to load one, it loads as black with no error message. I see your texture has a width of 320, which is not a power of two. I recommend using TexturePacker for creating your atlases. It has a setting for making the texture use power-of-two dimensions, defaults to on.